# How can I write the matrix of the following Linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Firstly I must apologise that I have tried Latex commands but they do not come out. So I hope my document is readable.

I have this definition of a linear transformation

```
T: P_n(R) -> P_n(R)
T(f(x))=f(x+1)
```

I have proved this to be a linear transformation (correct?) as follows:
Let

```
f(x)=A0+A1x+A2x^2+...+Anx^n, g(x)=B0+B1x+B2x^2+...+Bnx^n in P_{n}(R),
C,Ai,Bi in K, i=0,1,2,...,n
T(Cf(x)+g(x))=T(CA0+CA1x+CA2x^2+...+CAnx^n + B0+B1x+B2x^2+...+Bnx^n))
=CT(f(x))+T(g(x))
=Cf(x+1)+g(x+1)
```

So T is linear
Now I want to write a matrix representing this transformation relative to the basis {1, x-1, (x-1)^2, ... (x-1)^n}

```
T[1]=f(2) = ?(1) + ?(x-1) + ... + ?(x-1)^n
T[x-1]= f(x) =  ?(1) + ?(x-1) + ... + ?(x-1)^n
......
```

My problem is: What do I take as coefficients of the various basis elements, because
i) the evaluation of f(x+1) does not yield any coefficients
ii) replacing (x-1) by (x-1)+1 I lose the basis elements to

```
{1,x,x^n,...,x^n
```

Assistance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first proof, the step from line 3 to line 4 is incorrect. You need to write what $T(CA_0+CA_1x+CA_2x^2+...CA_nx^n+B_0+B_1x+B_2x^2+...+B_nx^n)$ is using the definition. What you did is using the fact that $T$ is linear to show it is linear.

It should be

$$T(CA_0+CA_1x+CA_2x^2+...CA_nx^n+B_0+B_1x+B_2x^2+...+B_nx^n)=CA_0+CA_1(x+1)+CA_2(x+1)^2+...CA_n(x+1)^n+B_0+B_1(x+1)+B_2(x+1)^2+...+B_n(x+1)^n$$

In the next question, $T(1)=1$ since if $f(x)=1$ then $f(x+1)$ is also $1$. You can use this idea to do the others.

To find the coefficients, you need to write $x^m$ in terms of $\{1, x-1, (x-1)^2, ..., (x-1)^n\}$. Make a change of variable $y=x-1$, so $x^m=(y+1)^m$. You can then easily find the coefficients of the $y$ terms.

Comment: Thanks @KittyL for the correction and for enlightening me. My concern was that I seem to be losing the original basis, which is

Comment: My concern was that I seem to be losing the original basis, {1, (x-1), (x-1)^2, ... }

Comment: I see. Sorry I didn't notice that. I will edit my answer.